# How to retrieve the column names for a checkbox group while using reactive function in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

When i select tbl1 the report is displaying but not the checkboxes with the variable(column names). From drop down i am able to select the different reports . For each report i need to display the corresponding column names as checkboxes and how can i add different caption to different reports. Thank you so much for the help.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny) 
library(DT)    
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
      tags$div(align = "center",style = "color:#3090C7;font-size: 50px;","TITLE"),
      tags$style(HTML("
   .tabbable > .nav > li > a {background-color:#728FCE;  color:black; width: 200PX;} ")),

      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About",
                         
                           tags$p(tags$h4("WELCOME PAGE" )) 
                           
      ),

      navbarMenu("Data Tables ",

                 tabPanel("MainTab1",
                          br(),
                          tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel("subtab1",
                                     br(),
                                     tabsetPanel(
                                       tabPanel("tab1",

                                                    selectInput("FILE", "Select the Report:",choices = c("tbl1","tbl2","tbl3")))),

                                               sidebarLayout(
                                                       sidebarPanel(width=3,
                                                                   checkboxGroupInput("col_n","Columns to display:",names(df),selected = names(df))

                                                       ),
                                                       mainPanel(
                                                       DT::dataTableOutput("table_data")  )

                                             )
                                             


                            ),

                            tabPanel("subtab2"),
                            tabPanel("subtab3")
                          )

                 )

                      ),

      tabPanel("Contact Us")

      )
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output,session) {


  df <-  reactive ({

    switch(input$FILE, "tbl1" = data.frame(lapply(subset(read_excel('test1.xlsx'),select= -c(ROWNUMBER,ORDER_ROWS)),as.character)),

           "tbl2" = data.frame(lapply(subset(read_excel('test2.xlsx'),select= -c(ROWNUMBER,ORDER_ROWS)),as.character)),
           "tbl3" = data.frame(lapply(subset(read_excel('test3.xlsx'),select= -c(ROWNUMBER,ORDER_ROWS)),as.character))
    )


  })



  output$table_data <-   DT::renderDataTable({
    #df()
    DT::datatable(data.frame(df()),
  
                   rownames = FALSE,

                   caption = "TOTAL LIVE BIRTHS BY PLACE OF OCCURRENCE AND PLACE OF RESIDENCE BY RACE ",
                   editable = TRUE,
                   extensions = 'Buttons',
                   filter = list(position = "top",clear = FALSE, plain = FALSE),
                   options = list(
                     lengthMenu = c(30, 50),
                     pageLength = nrow(df()),
                     scrollY =1600, scroller = TRUE, scrollX = T,
                     paging = TRUE,
                     searching = TRUE,
                     fixedColumns = TRUE,
                     autoWidth = TRUE,
                     ordering = TRUE,
                     dom = 'Bfrtip',#IF tB displays only few values
                     buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel','print'),
                     modifier = list(page = "current")),
                   class = "display nowrap compact" # style


    )
    #output$ui <-  renderUI(checkboxGroup("show_vars","Columns to display:" ))
                                         #,names(data.frame(df())),selected = names(data.frame(df()))))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I have updated the code . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your code for easier understanding et reproducibility.

I used `update...Input()` function to update the colnames input depending on the selected dataframe.
This kind of function exists for all shiny inputs, don't hesitate to check the documentation about them to learn how to use them.

This kind of action is always server side, not UI.

```
library(shiny) 
library(DT)    
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
      selectInput(
        "FILE", 
        "Select the Report:",
        choices = c("tbl1","tbl2","tbl3")),
      
      checkboxGroupInput(
        "col_n",
        "Columns to display:",
        choices = c() # initialize with empty
        ),

      DT::dataTableOutput("table_data")  
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  df <-  reactive ({ 
    switch(input$FILE, 
           "tbl1" = iris, # i replaced your datasets with base R datasets for reproducibility
           "tbl2" = mtcars,
           "tbl3" = faithful
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$FILE,{
    # do stuff whenever input$FILE is changed by the user
    req(df()) # we need df()
    
    #update input$col_n with colnames of selected dataset
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session,
      "col_n",
      choices = colnames(df()),
      selected = colnames(df())
    )
  })
 
  output$table_data <-   DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$col_n) # we need colnames
    
    DT::datatable(
      df() %>% select_at(input$col_n),
      rownames = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If your questions is resolved, please consider accepting the answer so it is marked as solved

Comment: @ gdevaux How can i add different captions to different data tables.output$table_data <- DT::renderDataTable({ req(input$col_n) DT::datatable( df() %>% select_at(input$col_n), rownames = FALSE, caption = "TOTAL tbl1 ") }) if i select tbl1 it should have tbl1 caption. If i select tbl2 it should have tbl2 caption. But here for each table it displays tbl1. textInput doesnt have list to add.How i can change the captions.Thank you again

Comment: Hi @Pop, i'm on holiday right now and cannot access R. You can ask a new question on StackOverflow and i'm sure you will get and answer soon